# how to capture gesture start outside from screen from left to right in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want the user slide right then to close the article detail page and return to article list page in Flutter. Now I am using GestureDetector and I could successfully capture the slide right gesture. This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/style.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/component/part_snippet.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/common/helpers.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/models/Item.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/page/profile.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/common/Repo.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

final partsProvider = FutureProvider.family((ref, int id) async {
  return await Repo.fetchItem(id);
});

class StoryInformation extends HookWidget {
  const StoryInformation({
    Key key,
    @required this.item,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Item item;

  void launchUrl(url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final parts = item.parts.map((i) => useProvider(partsProvider(i))).toList();

    Offset _initialSwipeOffset;
    Offset _finalSwipeOffset;

    void _onHorizontalDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
      _initialSwipeOffset = details.globalPosition;
    }

    void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
      _finalSwipeOffset = details.globalPosition;
    }

    void _onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
      if (_initialSwipeOffset != null) {
        final offsetDifference = _initialSwipeOffset.dx - _finalSwipeOffset.dx;
        final direction = offsetDifference > 0 ? print('left') : print('right');
        if (offsetDifference > 0) {
           // detect the right gesture, then back to main list page
        }
      }
    }

    return Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
          onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
          onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
          child: Padding(),
        ),
    )
 }
```

it works fine. But have a serious problem: when the user slide from left outside of sceen to right, the gesture not trigger, so the use must do the right gesture inside the screen from start to end. This experience was very wired.How to make it could capture the gesture outside from left screen, like ios silde right back action?

What I have tried:

1. if the x start position is 0, start from left side? but not work, the gesture action not trigger
2. add  `onTapDown and onTapUp`, still not work, not triggered.

I have read official document but did not list the situation. what should I do to make it work to capture the slide action outside screen from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

if you are detecting left to right
why do you have condition for right to left?

```
if (offsetDifference > 0) {}
```

You should have:

```
if (offsetDifference < 0) {}
```

Comment: This is aready implemented, I want to capture the slide start outside from screen. @man of knowledge